# Map parts of an aggregate to a List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, automapper

Let us say we have a simple business object:

```
class SimpleBO
{
   public string Field1{get;set;}
   public string Field2{get;set;}
}
```

Also we have a complex Aggregate like that:

```
class ComplexBO
{
    public SimpleBO SimpleBOField {get;set}
    public List<SomeClass> ObjectList {get;set;}
    public SomeClass Object {get;set;}
}
```

SomeClass itself has a reference of SimpleBO:

```
class SomeClass 
{
    public SimpleBO SimpleBOField {get;set}
}
```

Now in some part of my program I want to get a list of `all distinct` simple objects met inside a certain aggreggate. We are using automapper heavily but I did not manage to map it so far. May be a LINQ query is a better option? How would you solve this?

Comment: As defined every `SimpleBO` is distinct: unless you override equality operations (and `GetHash`) then reference objects have "reference identity".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you have is:

```
ComplexBO aggregate = ...
```

then you should just need:

```
var objects = aggregate.ObjectList.Select(x => x.SimpleBOField).Concat(
         new[] {aggregate.SimpleBOField, aggregate.Object.SimpleBOField }
    ).Distinct().ToList();
```

This will give you the distinct *object references*; if you need distinct *value pairs*, then either override `Equals()`/`GetHashCode()`, or cheat:

```
var objects = aggregate.ObjectList.Select(x => x.SimpleBOField).Concat(
         new[] {aggregate.SimpleBOField, aggregate.Object.SimpleBOField }
    ).Select(
         x => new {x.SimpleBOField.Field1, x.SimpleBOField.Field2}
    ).Distinct().Select(
         x => new SimpleBO {Field1 = x.Field1, Field2 = x.Field2}
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: It seems nice, do you think I should use this approach instead of automapper and why?

Comment: @Hohhi adjusted to compensate. I do not believe that Automapper is designed to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Do you think that logic is to complex to be called mapping?

Comment: @Hohhi well, it isn't exactly a standard projection!